# Firebase Web reference null in button onclick callback

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am trying to set a value to a database reference via the Firebase Web API. It works when I call the `set` function in a simple js script. However it doesn't get through when I try to do the same via a simple button.

**HTML code snippet:**

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Organiser</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js"></script>

        <form>
            <button id="sub"></button>
        </form>

    <script src="organiser_writer.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

**JS code snippet:**

```
(function() {
          // Initialize Firebase
    console.log("Initialising Firebase");
      var config = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);

    firebase.database().ref().child('events').set("WORKS");     
    const buttonsub = document.getElementById('sub');
    sub.onclick = function(){
        console.log("before");
        firebase.database().ref().child('events').set("DOESNT WORK");
        console.log("after");

    }


}());
```

"**WORKS**" will be written, but "**DOESNT WORK**" won't.

Comment: do you see the "before" and "after" console logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer to your problem would be doing:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('sub');
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('events');
    ref.set("This should work now");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the other logs inside the event handler print? Seems to me like they won't, so your problem is with handling the event.

You're using the wrong variable name, look at this lines:

```
const buttonsub = document.getElementById('sub');
sub.onclick = function() {
```

It should be:

```
const buttonsub = document.getElementById('sub');
buttonsub.onclick = function() {
```

Comment: Sorry Jaime, that was a typo. The real problem is that the page would reload when I'd click on the button that is not of type 'button'... hence recalling the script, setting the 'WORKS' keyword again ...